# display same image multiple times on Corona issue

Tags: image, coronasdk

[![enter image description here][1whileHello,

I have an issue in Corona while displaying the same image(blue bar) two times to be displayed as continuous layout to seem as one continuous image, but the issue is that the output shows as there was an edge between both images, here is my code:

img1 = display.newImage("dialog_b_mid.png",  _X/2, 770 )
    display.newImage("dialog_b_mid.png",  _X/2, 770 + img1.height)

and here is the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use images without borders on any side, this image has top or bottom border, and it looks like an edge between two images.
Obviously, you must avoid gradients.

You can create an image using a software like Photoshop, just create a new (rectangle) file and fill it with a color.
You can also use patterns or parallax backgrounds, learn more on Google.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Here is my output image]

I have attached my output here, sorry to forgot the attachemnt in the main post.

Comment: Maybe your image is not perfect  for continuous layout, have you tried other images?

Comment: Maybe you're right because I just tried another images and sounds good layout, so how can make my image support continuous layout and how can know that this image does not support?